# Can be Nginx installed with other than php-fpm?

Tags: nginx, php

All the tutorials, that I have found online, explain how to install Nginx with PHP-FPM! What is special about PHP-FPM and can Nginx be installed with PHP?

Regards

Comment: Nginx and PHP are two separate entities and do not combine much like how Apache + PHP does. Instead you'd install each on its own and then configure Nginx to send PHP requests to the FPM Process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to php-fpm official website :

> PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is an alternative PHP FastCGI
>   implementation with some additional features useful for sites of any
>   size, especially busier sites.
>
> ```
> These features include:
> ```
>
> - Adaptive process spawning (NEW!)
> - Basic statistics (ala Apache's mod_status) (NEW!)
> - Advanced process management with graceful stop/start
> - Ability to start workers with different uid/gid/chroot/environment and different php.ini (replaces safe_mode)
> - Stdout & stderr logging
> - Emergency restart in case of accidental opcode cache destruction
> - Accelerated upload support
> - Support for a "slowlog"
> - Enhancements to FastCGI, such as fastcgi_finish_request() - a special function to finish request & flush all data while continuing

and much more.....

it runs a service to accept php executation requests ... 
what do you excatly mean "PHP" ? do you want to run php executable with every page request ?

Comment: By PHP, I mean the normal build we usually use with Apache. I use PHP as a module with Apache. And that was not PHP-FPM, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: apache uses an internal parser module to serve requests . but it can be also configured to parse PHP scripts through an external FastCGI process, such as the PHP proces manager, php-fpm. This can increase the performance of PHP applications.
and i don't think nginx has any internal php parsers ....